# External GPU for macbook / mac mini

Tags: macos, mac, graphics-card

We use a mix of macbook pros and mac minis, from time to time we do some quite complicated cad modelling which takes a long time to render is there a way to hook up an external graphics card to the machines to help improve the speed ? As its seems the internal graphics cards (which are usually soldered to the mother board on compact machines) dont cut it.

Comment: Haven't used it, but looks promising. http://www.villageinstruments.com/tiki-index.php?page=ViDock

Comment: If your Mac Mini has a thunderbolt port then there are external GPU enclosures out there like @kobaltz pointed out. If you only have USB 2.0/3.0 then I am not sure if you have any options. Anyways, you should run a search for `external gpu`